# eBPF map concurrent update and delete in a loop

Tags: networking, kernel, ebpf

Target scenario is that I want to implementing a flow logging using ebpf program and attach the program to different network interfaces using tc.

So the ebpf map will looks like this:
key is a tuple of srcIp, srcPort, dstIp, dstPort, protocol.
value is a struct of bytesTransmitted and packetsTransmitted.

So when each packet is seen by network interface, I will update the map to increment the packets and bytes.

However, there is max size of the ebpf map, and I will need to periodically cleanup the stale entries in that map, otherwise the map will be full pretty quickly.

So I plan to implement a userspace program that will periodically expire the flow map entries.

However, what's the implication of accessing that map concurrently from both userspace program and kernel? Should I use bpf_spin_lock? I am worried that acquiring lock on each packet can be expensive.

I also found a post https://justin.azoff.dev/blog/bpf_map_get_next_key-pitfalls/, and the author is using a weird way to iterate and delete map entries. However, I also found this in the kernel source tree, which is just deleting items in a while loop. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/samples/bpf/trace_event_user.c#L108 Who is right and who is wrong? ( I guess I should trust kernel source tree more ).

Even with the example above, it's indicating that I can delete the map item while iterating the map. However, the post above did not mention anything like if I can concurrently updating the map element in the kernel.

I really appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, there is max size of the ebpf map, and I will need to periodically cleanup the stale entries in that map, otherwise the map will be full pretty quickly.
>
> So I plan to implement a userspace program that will periodically expire the flow map entries.

Another approach might be to use an LRU map.

> However, what's the implication of accessing that map concurrently from both userspace program and kernel? Should I use bpf_spin_lock? I am worried that acquiring lock on each packet can be expensive.

It depends on your goals. You are not required to use synchronization primitives when reading from user space. The syscall will copy the map value into the user supplied buffer after which it can't be modified. However, what can happen is the following:

Lets say our map value has 2 fields, field1 and field2. If my eBPF program increments both fields (field1++; field2++;). Then the copy in the syscall could happen in between these two modifications. So you could end up with a value that is a combination of the map state before and after the eBPF program ran. For most applications such as statistics this isn't an issue. But if for whatever reason changes within the map value need to be atomic, then you will have to use a spin_lock, which is not ideal for performance if you expect to update the same map values concurrently a lot.

For most stats related use-cases atomic operations from the eBPF side of per-CPU maps are enough to keep an accurate count. Then collect them periodically from userspace.

> Who is right and who is wrong?

Both are right, the first example wants to delete only part of the map and observes that after deleting a key from a map, it can't be used to get the next key after it, so you need to watch order of operations to avoid re-starting the loop and doing extra work. The second example simply removes all values and does not care if it restarts from the beginning.

So its alright to delete while iterating, but if you only want to do a partial deletion, you have to watch order of operations to not do extra work.

> Even with the example above, it's indicating that I can delete the map item while iterating the map. However, the post above did not mention anything like if I can concurrently updating the map element in the kernel.

It depends on what you mean my "can". You computer will not explode or crash, its allowed, but unfortunately there is no synchronization mechanism over multiple syscalls. So you can't read a map value, modify it in userspace and write it back without eBPF being able to modify it. So these modification by eBPF between the read and update syscalls will be lost. To only way I know to do something like this would be to use map-in-maps to swap out full maps atomically which brings challenges of its own.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for the info. I have a follow up question:

Let's assume I am iterating the bpf map and deleting the entries of the map in the userspace program, and concurrently, my ebpf program in kernel is trying to add an entry to the map (bpf_map_update_elem with BPF_NOEXIST flag) with a new key, is there any concern that might impact iteration in the userspace?

Comment: Reading through the kernel code, that seems valid since each element in the bpf map has a lock?

Comment: Maps are protected by an RCU mechanism so concurrent modification is "safe". But modification from kernel space can definitely mess with key iteration. If you are halfway through iterating and a key is added then you may encounter it or not. If you delete a key from bpf between two syscalls from userspace it might cause you to re-start from the beginning same as if you were to delete the key from userspace

Comment: Well, let's take my flow logs example. In the kernel, the ebpf program will just lookup element, or add a new key if that's a new tcp flow, and then increment the statistics. In the userspace program, it's trying to periodically iterate the map and delete stale flow log entries. I don't care if I see the newly added key or not, since if I don't see it, I will check then entry in my next iteration?

Comment: In that scenario it depends on the sort order of the new key and how far along the iterator is, so on average 50/50 if you will or will not see the new key.

Comment: This adds an atomic lookup_delete https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3e87f192b405960c0fe83e0925bd0dadf4f8cf43